How to fix "instruction tries to borrow reference for an account which is already borrowed" error
I'm writing a native solana program and from this code fragment i'm getting error:

"instruction tries to borrow reference for an account which is already
borrowed"

invoke_signed(
        &system_instruction::transfer(pda_account.key, &user, transfer_amount),
        &[[pda_account].clone()],
        &[&[b"hello", &[bump_seed]]],
    )?;

is there a way to drop any past borrowed references ?

I think you need to be aware how borrows / lifetimes work in Rust. Can you please try this:
{
    let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(pda_account.key, &user, transfer_amount);
    let accounts = &[pda_account.clone()]; 
    let seeds = &[&[b"hello", &[bump_seed]]];

    invoke_signed(
        &transfer_instruction,
        accounts,
        &[seeds],
    )?;
}

DO include the curly braces wrapping the code. They define the scope of the borrowed pda_account.
